# addEventListener always pointing to last element or id or objcet for all the addEventListener elements

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

Problem code

```
 var el = document.getElementById("searchcharm_'"+touch_id+"'");
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        openpopup("'"+popupurl+"'");
        sendpym("'"+touch_id+"'"); 
         });
```

I have used addEventListener to prevent default action of anchor tag. It worked well but my problem is addEventListener always pointing to last element or id  or objcet for all the elements in a page. For example if I have 10 image in page with 10 different ids add lister always points to id of last image, even if we clicked other image.

Entire code

```
var imgurl = "http:"+lcurl+touch_id+".jpg";
                 var data = "<div id=charm_"+touch_id+" data-charmid="+touch_id+" data-vis="+bgid+" data-vid="+seid+" data-vtitle="+vtitle_url+" data-title="+title_url+" style='float:left;' class='mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col charm-wrapper'>\n\
                <div class='mdl-card-wrapper charm-inner'>\n\
                  <div class='demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--8dp'>\n\
                        <div class='mdl-card__media'>\n\
                        "+locicon+"\n\
                      <a href='"+popupurl+"' id = searchcharm_'"+touch_id+"'>\n\
                      <div style='position:relative;'>\n\
                      <div style='position:absolute;z-index:9;right:0px;bottom:0px;'><img width=32px src="+cf_assets+"img/hanger.png></div>\n\
                       <div id=imagearea_"+touch_id+" title='"+title+"' class='imagearea loading'>\n\
                      </div></div></a>\n\
                    </div>\n\
                          <div class='mdl-card__title'>\n\
                    <div class='right-charm'>\n\
                     <div class='social-share'>\n\
                     "+copycontent+"\n\
                     "+watsapp+"\n\
                          <a onclick=sharetofb('"+ct_domain+socialshare_url+"'); title='Facebook' id=fb"+touch_id+" \n\
                  class='fb_share'></a>\n\
                <a onclick=sharetotwitter('"+ct_domain+socialshare_url+"'); title='Twitter' id=tw"+touch_id+" class='tw_share'> </a>\n\
                          </div>\n\
                          </div>\n\
                          <div class='icharm'>\n\
                      <h2 class='mdl-card__title-text'>"+subtitle+"</h2>\n\
                      <div class='mdl-card__subtitle-text'>"+title+"</div>\n\
                      <div id=vid_"+touch_id+" class='mdl-card__subtitle-videoname'>"+videoname+"</div>\n\
                       </div>\n\
                        </div>\n\
                      </div>\n\
                  </div>\n\
                </div>";
      $('#main-home-page-inner').add(HTML(data));
          callcloudinary(imgurl,title,touch_id);
          callmasonry();

      if(i == setarr.length-1){


         localStorage.touchids=touchid_arr.join(",");
        localStorage.searchresults=gcharmarr.join(",");
     }

       var el = document.getElementById("searchcharm_'"+touch_id+"'");
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        openpopup("'"+popupurl+"'");
        sendpym("'"+touch_id+"'"); 
         });

     // document.getElementById("main-home-page-inner").innerHTML += html;

    }
    /* document.getElementById("fb"+touch_id).setAttribute("onclick","sharetofb('"+title+"','"+text+"','"+ct_domain+socialshare_url+"','"+social_domain+lcurl+touch_id+".jpg')");*/
  }

           })
           .error(function(status, statusText, responseText) {
                //console.log(statusText);
                //console.log(responseText);
           });


    Kindly help.
```

Answer (score 1):

(Answering since I can't comment)

I can't see all of your code, but I'm assuming you're using some sort of loop to iterate through an array called setarr. You need to create a closure at each iteration of the loop, else the local variables at each iteration will equal whatever the local variables are when the function terminates.

Read more about closures here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any increment value for the touch_id that is why you always get same ID for the multiple DIV and it always point to last.